# How to specify a custom element to display the autocompletions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'd like to display the suggested autocompletions in a separate `div`, not as a pop-up menu displayed over the designated autocomplete widget. The reason for this is: we're using autocomplete as a way to help the user see that they're about to attempt a duplicate entry. As they type in the input field, a div will show the progressive matches.

I'm doing my testing with the autocomplete sample code, "birds" with a remote data source:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

  $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      log( ui.item ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've just been using the "birds" demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and trying to get the search results into a new div that I create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

  $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $('.newDiv ul').empty();
      },
     change: function(event, ui) {
        $('.newDiv ul').empty();
     }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {    
      return $('<li/>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append(item.value)
        .appendTo($('.newDiv ul'));
    };
  });
```

Html:

```
<div class="newDiv"><ul></ul></div>
```

Comment: Umm... maybe! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I'm confused - what should the initial static html look like in order to use this?

Comment: Hey, that's awesome. For me, it's appending the results after every AJAX call. How would I adapt it to clear the list before each time? (I'm guessing that your .empty() was meant to do this - for some reason it's not.)

Comment: you can try adding "change" function which is called on blur of input box, as added in answer above, hope that works

Answer (score 1):

While there is no provision in Autocomplete to achieve what you want, this trick here may work for you - [How to customize jquery autocomplete for displaying in a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915496/how-to-customize-jquery-autocomplete-for-displaying-in-a-div)

Comment: That might be good enough; especially if I can move the div/menu around to a good location - will test this out.